# uwp : vendor specific device via usb connenction

Tags: uwp, usb, driver

is it possible to use external device via usb with vendor driver in UWP app?

i searched some post and they said the driver should be winsys and the appxmanifest file should be modified

but the vendor driver type is libusb-win32

is there any solution with this situation?

Comment: Does this device support `SerialCommunication` ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT unfortunately it has usb, ethernet port only

Comment: Could you please try use [this code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) to enumerate this device within UWP?

Comment: i run c++ app in the code sample and the app can not detect the device

Comment: Which device selector you used when device enumerated?

Comment: And have you checked this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-connect-to-a-usb-device--uwp-app-) how to access to usb device.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT first, i use "All Device Interfaces(default)"  for device selector and 
i found now that in scenario 7 "Request Specific DeviceinformationKin" i can see the device in "DeviceContainer"
and in the official document the winusb.sys should be loaded as device driver but libusb-win32 driver is loaded now.

Comment: Could you mind share which document you have read about uwp does not support `libusb-win32` driver?